# Wordpress doesn't display the previous articles

Tags: wordpress

My blog is: [www.ferven.tk](http://www.ferven.tk)

If you try to click button 2, in home, you can see that the page is reloaded but does not show the previous articles. 
How is it possible? I configured everything to perfection.

```
 <?php
 /*
 Template Name: Blog - Masonry
 */
 get_header(); global $gp_settings; ?>

<?php wp_enqueue_script( 'isotope' ); ?>

<?php gp_page_header( get_the_ID() ); ?>

<div id="content-wrapper"<?php if ( $gp_settings['layout'] != 'fullwidth' ) { ?> class="container"<?php } ?>>

<div id="content">

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>     
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; endif; rewind_posts(); ?>           

    <?php 

    $args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_gp_posts_per_page', true ),
    'paged'          => $paged,
    );

    $featured_query = new wp_query( $args ); if ( $featured_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

        <div class="post-wrapper blog-masonry">

            <?php while ( $featured_query->have_posts() ) : $featured_query->the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'post', 'loop' ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

        </div><!-- END POST WRAPPER -->

        <?php gp_pagination( $featured_query->max_num_pages ); ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <span class="error"><?php _e( 'No posts found.', 'gp_lang' ); ?></span>

    <?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

</div><!-- END CONTENT -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

Comment: please provide some of your code

Comment: What code do I need to provide? 
I just installed wordpress and activated the vivacity theme

Comment: Ok i have update the post with the code that i have found in my theme.

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: try to click on button "2" in the home of the blog.